# how to extract text from PDF file using python , i never did this and not getting the DOM of PDF file

Tags: python-3.x

this is my PDF file "https://drive.google.com/open?id=1M9k1AO17ZSwT6HTrTrB-uz85ps3WL1wS"

Help me someone to extract this , as i search on SO getting some clue to extract text using these libries PyPDF2, PyPDF2.pdf , PageObject, u_, ContentStream, b_, TextStringObject ,but not getting how to use it.

someone please help me to extract this with some explanation, so i can understand the code and tell me how to read DOM of PDF file.

Answer (score 0):

you need to install some libaries:
`pip install PyPDF2`
`pip install textract`
`pip install nltk`
This will download the libraries you require t0 parsePDF documents and extract keywords. In order to do this, make sure your PDF file is stored within the folder where you’re writing your script.

Startup your favourite editor and type:

Note: All lines starting with # are comments.

Step 1: Import all libraries:

```
import PyPDF2 
import textract
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
```

Step 2: Read PDF File

```
#write a for-loop to open many files -- leave a comment if you'd #like to learn how
filename = 'enter the name of the file here' 
#open allows you to read the file
pdfFileObj = open(filename,'rb')
#The pdfReader variable is a readable object that will be parsed
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
#discerning the number of pages will allow us to parse through all #the pages
num_pages = pdfReader.numPages
count = 0
text = ""
#The while loop will read each page
while count < num_pages:
    pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(count)
    count +=1
    text += pageObj.extractText()
#This if statement exists to check if the above library returned #words. It's done because PyPDF2 cannot read scanned files.
if text != "":
   text = text
#If the above returns as False, we run the OCR library textract to #convert scanned/image based PDF files into text
else:
   text = textract.process(fileurl, method='tesseract', language='eng')
# Now we have a text variable which contains all the text derived #from our PDF file. Type print(text) to see what it contains. It #likely contains a lot of spaces, possibly junk such as '\n' etc.
# Now, we will clean our text variable, and return it as a list of keywords.
```

Step 3: Convert text into keywords

```
#The word_tokenize() function will break our text phrases into #individual words
tokens = word_tokenize(text)
#we'll create a new list which contains punctuation we wish to clean
punctuations = ['(',')',';',':','[',']',',']
#We initialize the stopwords variable which is a list of words like #"The", "I", "and", etc. that don't hold much value as keywords
stop_words = stopwords.words('english')
#We create a list comprehension which only returns a list of words #that are NOT IN stop_words and NOT IN punctuations.
keywords = [word for word in tokens if not word in stop_words and not word in punctuations]
```

Now you have keywords for your file stored as a list. You can do whatever you want with it. Store it in a spreadsheet if you want to make the PDF searchable, or parse a lot of files and conduct a cluster analysis. You can also use it to create a recommender system for resumes for jobs ;)