# VScode using Python, Anaconda for text extraction

Tags: python, shell, visual-studio-code, conda

I am using Python 3.7.10 on VSCode, and a Windows 10 64bit.

My Level:
Beginner

What do I want to do?
I have a PDF bilingual, and I want to extract the English part, sentence after sentence, so basically the whole document. In the end I want another PDF with only the English part.

What did I do?
I tried different methods, but none seems to work.

Up until now, I was able to import the packages that I found under this thread: [how to extract text from PDF file using python , i never did this and not getting the DOM of PDF file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55255667/how-to-extract-text-from-pdf-file-using-python-i-never-did-this-and-not-gettin)
in my Jupyter-Notebook.

The packages are in the directory, which is also mentioned in the settings.json in VScode:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "C:\\Users\\username\\Anaconda3\\envs\\condaenv\\python.exe",
    "jupyter.jupyterServerType": "local"
}
```

Where am I stuck? I don't really get the problem, which is very common, as many people try to find solution to a similar problem. The most known solution is that it might be in another directory, but it is not. Also, I cannot find the guideline, how to find, where my notebook is retrieving the packages, from which directory. Or on how I can tell in VScode my notebook, what directory it should use. I thought this might be done in settings.json.
So my problems are: the script from link above cannot find my pdf, and a Shell error

---

My code:

```
import PyPDF2
import textract
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
#write a for-loop to open many files -- leave a comment if you'd #like to learn how
filename = 'q.pdf'
#open allows you to read the file
pdfFileObj = open('q.pdf','rb')
#The pdfReader variable is a readable object that will be parsed
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
#discerning the number of pages will allow us to parse through all #the pages
num_pages = pdfReader.numPages
count = 0
text = ""
#The while loop will read each page
while count < num_pages:
    pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(count)
    count +=1
    text += pageObj.extractText()
#This if statement exists to check if the above library returned #words. It's done because PyPDF2 cannot read scanned files.
if text != "":
   text = text
#If the above returns as False, we run the OCR library textract to #convert scanned/image based PDF files into text
else:
   text = textract.process('C:/Users/username/Documents/DA_Project/q.pdf', method='tesseract', language='eng')
# Now we have a text variable which contains all the text derived #from our PDF file. Type print(text) to see what it contains. It #likely contains a lot of spaces, possibly junk such as '\n' etc.
# Now, we will clean our text variable, and return it as a list of keywords.
#The word_tokenize() function will break our text phrases into #individual words
tokens = word_tokenize(text)
#we'll create a new list which contains punctuation we wish to clean
punctuations = ['(',')',';',':','[',']',',']
#We initialize the stopwords variable which is a list of words like #"The", "I", "and", etc. that don't hold much value as keywords
stop_words = stopwords.words('english')
#We create a list comprehension which only returns a list of words #that are NOT IN stop_words and NOT IN punctuations.
keywords = [word for word in tokens if not word in stop_words and not word in punctuations]
```

---

Error Message:
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\textract\parsers\utils.py in run(self, args)
83                 args,
---> 84                 stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
85             )

```
~\Anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\subprocess.py in __init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds, encoding, errors, text)
    799                                 errread, errwrite,
--> 800                                 restore_signals, start_new_session)
    801         except:

~\Anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\subprocess.py in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, unused_restore_signals, unused_start_new_session)
   1206                                          os.fspath(cwd) if cwd is not None else None,
-> 1207                                          startupinfo)
   1208             finally:

**FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden**

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ShellError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-745599b9b2eb> in <module>
     23 #If the above returns as False, we run the OCR library textract to #convert scanned/image based PDF files into text
     24 else:
---> 25    text = textract.process('C:/Users/username/Documents/DA_Project/q.pdf', method='tesseract', language='eng')
     26 # Now we have a text variable which contains all the text derived #from our PDF file. Type print(text) to see what it contains. It #likely contains a lot of spaces, possibly junk such as '\n' etc.
     27 # Now, we will clean our text variable, and return it as a list of keywords.

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\textract\parsers\__init__.py in process(filename, encoding, extension, **kwargs)
     75 
     76     parser = filetype_module.Parser()
---> 77     return parser.process(filename, encoding, **kwargs)
     78 
     79 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\textract\parsers\utils.py in process(self, filename, encoding, **kwargs)
     44         # output encoding
     45         # http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain/unipain.html#35
---> 46         byte_string = self.extract(filename, **kwargs)
     47         unicode_string = self.decode(byte_string)
     48         return self.encode(unicode_string, encoding)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\textract\parsers\pdf_parser.py in extract(self, filename, method, **kwargs)
     31             return self.extract_pdfminer(filename, **kwargs)
     32         elif method == 'tesseract':
---> 33             return self.extract_tesseract(filename, **kwargs)
     34         else:
     35             raise UnknownMethod(method)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\textract\parsers\pdf_parser.py in extract_tesseract(self, filename, **kwargs)
     55         contents = []
     56         try:
---> 57             stdout, _ = self.run(['pdftoppm', filename, base])
     58 
     59             for page in sorted(os.listdir(temp_dir)):

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\textract\parsers\utils.py in run(self, args)
     89                 # This is equivalent to getting exitcode 127 from sh
     90                 raise exceptions.ShellError(
---> 91                     ' '.join(args), 127, '', '',
     92                 )
     93 

**ShellError: The command `pdftoppm C:/Users/username/Documents/DA_Project/q.pdf C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpd_xu6afp\conv` failed with exit code 127
------------- stdout -------------
------------- stderr -------------**
```

Comment: Could you please provide us with an example that can minimize the recurrence of this problem? Have you run your code in a system terminal outside of VS Code?

Comment: @JillCheng python 3.9 shell:

pdfFileObj = open('q.pdf','rb')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'q.pdf'
                                                                 ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: Please try to give a path to the "pdf" file in the code and provide the complete code snippet you used that we can reproduce this problem.

Comment: Have you tried to test this code in a system terminal outside of VS Code?

Comment: -It is recommended that you check whether the python used by the current terminal is the python environment where you installed the module, or you could reinstall the module in this environment.

Comment: @JillCheng what weird is that if I run import etc. in Python's IDLE I get the error message as above already in the first line. If I run the script in Windows command prompt then I get the message at exact same line, as above described. The interpreter has difficulties finding my pdf text and has issues with the "shell"? So either I am writing the path to my pdf wrong or the command prompt or the vscode do not understand, what I want from them. If you have any other option to extract english text from scanned  pdf, then please let me know. Thanks!